# How can I find WebOrb for .NET Community Edition?

Tags: weborb

So, this may sound stupid but I don't really get it. When I visited http://www.themidnightcoders.com and download WebOrb for .NET. After I finished product setup progress, I realize that the product that I just downloaded and setup in my machine was "Enterprise Edition in Development mode"

Because when I go into the product web console page. It tell me that, it's in development mode and limit for on 5 IP Addresses. When I return to download-page of WebOrb site I only found one product for download and it's the one that I just downloaded.

So I want to use WebOrb for .NET Community Edition but I have not found it yet.

May you please tell me the solution of this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/faqs.html

Where can I find Community Edition?
Please contact sales at 1-888-MYWEBORB or sales@themidnightcoders.com to get a free WebORB Community Edition license. (Only one per company.)

Answer (score 0):

You can find WebORB Community Edition on the product editions page for both WebORB for .NET and WebORB for Java.  Here is a link to the request form:

http://www.themidnightcoders.com/community-edition-application.html